# Bash - echo username with backslash to file

Tags: linux, bash

Linux newbie here, but I have a script that is supposed to create a file:

```
VI_USERNAME=domain\\user
echo "VI_USERNAME=$VI_USERNAME" >> .visdkrc
```

File looks like this:

```
VI_USERNAME=domain  user
```

How can I get my output to looks like this:

VI_USERNAME=domain\user

Comment: Ok. But what is your question?

Comment: The `echo` documentation tells you not to use it for strings that contain backslashes. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, and follow its advice (see in particular the APPLICATION USAGE section).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do backslashes disappear when run through echo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10238617/608639), [Print variable with backslashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/329259/56041), [Escape backslash in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9487303/608639), [How to echo a double backslash plus a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25678262/608639), [Bash parameter expansion rules for backslash character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36012736/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not happen with `bash` with the code you describe (protip: always test your own example):

```
$ cat myfile
VI_USERNAME=domain\\user
echo "VI_USERNAME=$VI_USERNAME" >> .visdkrc

$ bash myfile

$ cat .visdkrc
VI_USERNAME=domain\user
```

However, something similar happens with `dash` when the username starts with a "t":

```
$ cat myfile
VI_USERNAME=domain\\thatotherguy
echo "VI_USERNAME=$VI_USERNAME" >> .visdkrc

$ dash myfile

$ cat .visdkrc
VI_USERNAME=domain      hatotherguy
```

(you may be using `sh`, which calls `dash` and not `bash` on Debian based distros since 2011)

The general rule about `echo` is that if you have to ask, use `printf` instead:

```
VI_USERNAME=domain\\user
printf '%s\n' "$VI_USERNAME" >> .visdkrc
```

`echo` is a legacy command that treats data differently across platforms and shells, especially with regard to flags and backslash sequences.

`printf` is well defined and has fewer pitfalls.